# How can I get an array containing all the Keys from a properties file in the correct sequence?

Tags: java, properties

I have the following **.properties** file:

> 0.0=value1
>
> 2.3=value2
>
> 2.45=value3
>
> 2.65=value4
>
> 2.71=value5
>
> 2.87=value6
>
> 3.66=value7

I want to get an array with the keys from this file, something containing this:

```
[0.0, 2.3, 2.45, 2.65, 2.71, 2.87, 3.66]
```

I tried this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
FileInputStream myInputStream;
myInputStream = new FileInputStream("./test.properties");
prop.load(myInputStream);
myInputStream.close();
Set set = prop.keySet();
Object vetKey[] = set.toArray();
```

But my set does not contain the keys in the order they appear in the file,

I don't know the reason, they appear like this:

> [2.71, 3.66, 2.45, 2.3, 0.0, 2.65, 2.87]

How can I get an array with the correct sequence of keys? Like they are in the **.properties**:?

Comment: You should know that set do not have a ordering. so when you put it in a set it loose ordering. You can use [propertyNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#propertyNames()). Haven't tried it so I'm not user if ordering will be preserved.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using Properties for this purpose? It is not intended for this. It is just used for saving/storing/retrieving properties for your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a `BufferedReader` instead.  Read each line into a string then use `string.split` to split each line at the '=' signs.  Add `array[0]` from the string.split to your properties array.  They'll be in order.  Not the best way to do this, but it will get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.sort();` or `Collections.sort();`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using prop.keys() rather than prop.keySet()? There's a difference between wanting them in the order that they occur in the properties file and having them in sorted order. If you want them sorted, then sort them using Collections.sort()